# Connections vs Sessions vs Transactions

Tags: h2

What is the difference between the following three concepts?

1. a JDBC connection
2. an H2 session
3. a JDBC transaction

Does a session span multiple connections? Does a session span multiple transactions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For H2, a session and a connection are the same thing.

An H2 transaction is a regular [database transaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction).

Comment: So a single Session/Connection may contain multiple transactions. Is that correct?

Comment: what do you exactly mean by "contain multiple transactions"? Once you have a connection object you can create multiple queries and open multiple transactions. You can even have nested transactions where you open a transaction inside another open transaction. The behaviour is explained on this wikipedia page [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_transaction)

Comment: For H2, one session/connection can only have one top-level transaction open at any given time. But a session/connection may commit multiple transactions (one after the other).

Comment: @ThomasMueller I am observing (via debug) distinct Connections (based on connection.id) which contain the same Session (based on the connection.session.id).  This is within a Spring Boot Test environment with TX management enabled.  Is this expected?